# How to write a Junit test to Verify Retry on ReadTimeout/Exception for an API

Tags: java, junit, timeout, micronaut, wiremock

I want to test the read timeout for an api which my application is calling using micronaut httpclient.

```
@Validated
@Client("${api.url}")
public interface ApiClient {
    @Get("/v1/itemdetails{?ids*}")
    @Retryable(attempts = "${attempts:3}", delay = "${delay:1s}")
    HttpResponse<ItemDto> getItems(
            @NotEmpty List<String> ids,
            @Header("authorization") @NotBlank String authorization
    );
}
```

Code which call this client is as follows:

```
private void saveItems(List<String> ids) {
    try {
        String token = getToken();
        HttpResponse<ItemDto> itemResponse =ApiClient.getItems(ids,token);
        handleItemResponse(ids, itemResponse);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error saving items", e);
    }
}
```

How I can write a Test to verify whether Retry is happening 3 times or not? I already configure Wiremock to respond with a delay more than ReadTimeout Value.

One way I know is that I can put an ApiClient call inside another method with `Retryable` annotation and verify the number of times `getItems` method gets called.

```
@Retryable(attempts = "${attempts:3}", delay = "${delay:1s}")
private HttpResponse<ItemDto> getItemsFromApi(List<String> ids){
   logs.debug("calling Api...");
   return ApiClient.getItems(ids,token);
}
```

Please suggest if there's any better approach to test this.